# How to load resource-bundles from dependency jar in a jsf web application

Tags: java, jsf, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm trying to load a resource bundle from a dependency jar in my web application. Intellij can resolve stuff like:

```
#{common['key']}
```

but payara throws an error: "Can't find bundle for base name common, locale de_DE".

My project looks like this:

```
Dependency Jar:
    resources /
        META-INF /
            - common.properties
            - faces-config.xml

Web Application:
    resources /
        - messages.properties
    webapp /
        WEB-INF /
           - faces-config.xml
```

The faces-config.xml in the dependency jar looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.2"
          xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
    <application>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>common</base-name>
            <var>common</var>
        </resource-bundle>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

The faces-config.xml in the web application looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.2"
          xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
    <application>
        <resource-handler>org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.UnmappedResourceHandler</resource-handler>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>common</base-name>
            <var>common</var>
        </resource-bundle>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>messages</base-name>
            <var>messages</var>
        </resource-bundle>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

I also tried removing the common resource-bundle from the webapp's faces-config but that did not help.

What can I do to access the messages from the other jar file?

Comment: Do you have your "Dependency Jar" added to the classpath on application server?

Comment: Yes I did that.

Comment: Is it possible to share sample project for investigation?